# Magento(1.9.1.0) whole breadcrumb not showing, only home breadcrumb is showing

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

[image]

I have a custom module which has the templates and I want to display the breadcrumb on a page. The fields are highlighted in the image in which I want to display breadcrumb. For e.g., I have a link https://link.com/parth-valves-and-hoses-llp/contact-us and I want the breadcrumb like this `Home >   Bazar Directory >   Parth Valves and Hoses LLP >  Contact Us`.